# Partial derivative and polar coordinates

Tags: partial-derivative, problem-solving

[Picture of the solved problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG1Az.jpg)

I will be thankful if somebody check if I  solved it correctly.

Comment: When you calculate the partial derivative of the angle and the y coordinate, you make mistake, is: $\frac{x}{r^2}$, not $\frac{x^3}{r^2}$

Comment: Pass the function into x,y coordinates, I think the result is different and that's the correct one

Comment: Oh, yes you are right . I dont understand why to pass the function in x,y coordinates.

Comment: Oh nothing I didn't remember how to split a partial derivative into the partial derivatives of other variables and thought your * and ** step were wrong but now i know tris step is fine.

Comment: Except for what I mentioned, it seems correct.